# Change GH-pages URL without sub directories for Portfolio

Tags: url, github, github-pages

Hey currently my Portfolio is being hosted at https://etiotan.github.io/portfolio/app/   through githubpages

I would instead like it to be hosted from this URL

https://etiotan.github.io

I know there is a way to do but I just cant figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your repository named after `username.github.io` so in your case `etiotan.github.io`. Check [this link](https://pages.github.com/) for more information.

You'll also need either :

- to move your app content (html/css/js) to the root of your repo on your `gh-pages` branch

So your `gh-pages` will look like :

```
├── css/
├── js/
├── minjs/
├── pug/
├── sass/
├── favicon.ico
├── index.pug
└── index.html
```

- or create a new `index.html` at the root of your repo on your `gh-pages` branch which will redirect to your `app/index.html`

Comment: Thank you, i'm only struggling to get the redirect working on the index.html in the root file. but you have been a lot of help!